# debugging several projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution mainly written in c sharp. This solution has 10 projects, one of them contains the web forms. This web forms get the data from another project. However, I am receiving null data. In order to debug this, I would like to setup the web forms project as the start project but the problem that I'm getting is that I don't see what is going on on the other project, the one that passes the data. How can I reach this project when debugging? Any solutions? The other project just contains classes, it is not dealing with the database either yet.

Thanks

Comment: there is one project that deals with the database, and then, most of the projects are classes to model the data or to modify it, apart from the web forms

Comment: you might be able to peek in to in to by stepping in to the method calls

Comment: You didnt mention if you are using breakpoints, trying putting break points on part of the code which guaranteed to be executed in the project you think you are unable to reach. Might be a good start to address your issue.

Comment: Are you starting multiple projects for debug?

Comment: F10 or F11 (step into or step over) are not getting me to the other classes

Comment: I am using breakpoints on the next class and in the web forms, but I don't see what is going on either,

Comment: what do you  mean by starting multiple projects for debug?

Comment: Make sure every project are correctly referenced in the other project. Execute the Win form. Break point on the get data. Press F11

Comment: I just run multiple vs instances :D

Comment: Please share your solution structure about how they are referenced, which could help us confirm whether there has any problem on solution structure. And also please tell us every project type in your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorted! it was a silly mistake, the interface was misspelled, it should be IClass, being Class the class name, somehow, it was misspelled

Comment: Since it was resolved, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue as yours. Thanks for your sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the solution to start multiple projects at once?
Right click on "Solution Explorer", click on "Properties", select "Multiple startup projects" and choose what projects you want to start together by changing the dropdow from "none" to "start". It should work.

Comment: Or Debug the starting project and right click on the other project in explorer. then Debug> Start in new instance

Comment: A project with an Output Type of Class  Library can not be starter, I get that error when trying.

Comment: Hmm one of your projects is a library then.. so you can't do that. Have you checked if every project is referenced correctly as Drag and Drop suggested? If they're all in the same solution, you should reference them as a project. (Add References -> Projects).
Then put a breakpoint on the library call and hitting F11 should work.

Comment: apart from the immediate project yes, that one says that there is a circular reference

Comment: Circular reference means this project (A) is referencing another project (B) that is referencing that project (A) again, and this doesn't make sense. 
Check wich projects references the data project and wich projects are referenced by the data project. There should not be a duplicate project reference from your solution there.